# Ghidra : unable to find PDB and Couldn't find type info structure

Tags: pdb, ghidra

I downloaded Ghidra about a week ago(I am new to reverse engineering), I did what the tutorial video from Ghidra official site was showing, I made a simple C++ program to Visual Studio, the program has an infinity while(`while(1)`) that prints "Hello World!" to the screen(`std::cout << "Hello World!";`).
I used Ghidra to disassemble that program as the person at the tutorial did it, but I am getting errors.

**The errors :**

```
PDB> ERROR: Unable to locate the DIA SDK. It is required to load PDB files.
* See docs/README_PDB.html for DLL registration instructions.


PDB> ERROR: Unable to locate the DIA SDK. It is required to load PDB files.
* See docs/README_PDB.html for DLL registration instructions.


Windows x86 PE RTTI Analyzer> Couldn't find type info structure.
```

I saw "README_PDB.html", I did what it said there to do, but still the errors, all of them, where there.

After some time I found out that the folder my `.exe` was stored had also a [name of my exe].pdb file and that when you choose analyzers there is an analyzer "PDB" and if you click on it will let you insert a path, tried to insert the path to the parent folder of that .pdb, but still nothing changed.

**So :**
How can I make this work, please anyone, I am desperate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the error, it seems you are running ghidra on Windows, and the error is referred to at the [README_PDB](https://github.com/NationalSecurityAgency/ghidra/blob/master/Ghidra/Features/PDB/src/global/docs/README_PDB.html) and [load_pdb](https://github.com/NationalSecurityAgency/ghidra/blob/master/Ghidra/Features/Base/src/main/help/help/topics/ImporterPlugin/load_pdb.html) sites. Maybe the problem is with Visual Studio rather than ghidra.

Quoting from there:

> In order for the native PDB parser to work on your Microsoft
>   Windows machine, you must:
>
> 1. Ensure you have
>      *msdia140.dll* on your computer, and
> 2. Register
>      *msdia140.dll* in the Windows registry.

and:

> The following instructions assume you have a 64-bit operating
>   system.  If you have rebuilt  pdb.exe with a newer version of the DIA
>   SDK you will need to register the corresponding  version of the 64-bit
>   DLL.  The DIA SDK 14.0 corresponds to Visual Studio 2017.
>
> The PDB format is known to change over time and may be
>   incompatible with the current *pdb.exe* parser contained within
>   Ghidra.  A Microsoft Visual Studio project is provided within the
>   *Ghidra/Features/PDB/src/pdb* directory which will allow you to
>   rebuild it with a newer version  of Visual Studio and DIA SDK.

Comment: I use Visual Studio 2019, maybe that's the problem, also I did the "msdia140.dll" registration as it was written in the README_PDB(cmd, "register [path to msdia140.dll],  and a window saying that the registration was successful popped up,  so I don't know

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 msdia140.dll does not work with the Ghidra 9.1.2 pdb.exe.  In order to build a new Ghidra pdb.exe that works with the Visual Studio 2019 msdia140.dll, you should use the Visual Studio project mentioned in the last bullet of inverzeio's response.  $(GHIDRA)\Ghidra\Features\PDB\src\pdb\README.txt explains how to do that.

msdia140.dll must also be registered, as described in $(GHIDRA)\docs\README_PDB.html.